# Querying comma-separated lists of values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called Students with Columns Name and Skills.
Name is varchar type and Skills contains skills of the students in CSV format. 
Eg:

```
Name    Skills
ABC     C,Python,JAVA
XYZ     C,Python,C#
UT      C,SQL,JS,CSS
```

I want to display a a table like this

```
Name    C     C++     C#      Python      JAVA      SQL        JS        CSS
ABC     1     0       0         1         0        0            0         0
XYZ     1     0       1          1        0        0            0         0
```

How do I do this? 
Also, Each Student studies in a college. 
I want to display the College name in place of the Name Column.
And the Columns under Skills need to be the COUNT of NUMBER of STUDENTS with each SKILL.

Comment: I thinks its time to use a bunch of case stateements

Comment: First revise the table to store one name/skill pair per row.  Storing multiple skills in one field makes it difficult to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Limey, Could you help me out with that, please? I am really just a beginner and I have given this thing hours now.

Comment: @HansUp, sorry, It can't be done now.

Comment: Your data is essentially unusable.  @HansUp gave you a good suggestion.  You should take a look at why you think it can't be done.  Also, since you say you are a beginner and you have a very bad database design, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @DanBracuk, what about using CASE? I've heard its the answer to my problem?

Comment: Access SQL does not support the 'CASE WHEN' construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree with the comments that you ***really should*** fix your table structure. However, if you need an ugly hack for the time being you *might* get away with something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Name],
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,C,*",1,0) AS C,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,Python,*",1,0) AS Python,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,CSS,*",1,0) AS CSS
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [Name],
            "," & Skills & "," AS Skillz
        FROM tblSkills
    )
```

The trick is to glue a comma onto the beginning and the end of the Skills column so in each case you only search for something like `"*,C,*"` instead of `"C,*" Or "*,C,*" Or "*,C"`.

Also, watch out for "funny characters" in case they confuse the LIKE operator or produce troublesome column names.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Also, I don;t understand the second select statement.

Comment: @shashlearner The second SELECT statement is the subquery that glues the commas onto the beginning and end of the data (instead of modifying the data in the table itself). As for "not working", before posting my answer I tested that exact query from within Access 2010 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you come to chat? I'd very very grateful!