# Querying Comma Separated Values Grouped by Column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table called Students with Columns: Student Name, College and Skills.
Student Name is varchar type and Skills contains skills of the students in CSV format. Also, Gender column has either 'M' or 'F'
Eg:

```
College Skills                  Student Name
ABC     C,Python,Python,JAVA    S1
ABC     C,Python,JAVA,CSS       S2
ABC     C,Python,JAVA,JS,C#     S3
ABC     C,Python,JAVA           S4
XYZ     C,Python,C#             S5
XYZ     C,Python,C#             S6
XYZ     C,Python,C#             S7
UT      C,SQL,JS,CSS            S8
```

I want to display a a table like this

```
College   Men Women  C     C++     C#      Python      JAVA      SQL        JS        CSS
ABC       2     2    4     0       1         4         4        0            1         1
XYZ       1     2    3     0       3         3         0        0            0         0
UT        1     0    1     0       0         0         0        1            1         1
```

How do I do this?

I have made a query which displays all the students which possess the SKILLS as 1 or 0.
But this leads to a lot of duplication.

I have used IIF statement in the select to get columns Skills Columns and each row is a student. But I want each row to be a College and not a Student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19431498/2144390), the revised query

```sql
SELECT
    [Student Name],
    College,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,C,*",1,0) AS _C,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,Python,*",1,0) AS _Python,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,JAVA,*",1,0) AS _JAVA,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,CSS,*",1,0) AS _CSS,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,JS,*",1,0) AS _JS,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,C#,*",1,0) AS _CSharp,
    IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,SQL,*",1,0) AS _SQL
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [Student Name],
            College,
            "," & Skills & "," AS Skillz
        FROM Students
    )
```

returns

```
Student Name  College  _C  _Python  _JAVA  _CSS  _JS  _CSharp  _SQL
------------  -------  --  -------  -----  ----  ---  -------  ----
S1            ABC       1        1      1     0    0        0     0
S2            ABC       1        1      1     1    0        0     0
S3            ABC       1        1      1     0    1        0     0
S4            ABC       1        1      1     0    0        0     0
S5            XYZ       1        1      0     0    0        0     0
S6            XYZ       1        1      0     0    0        0     0
S7            XYZ       1        1      0     0    0        0     0
S8            UT        1        0      0     1    1        0     1
```

So, now all we need to do is add an outer query to add up the values

```sql
SELECT 
    College, 
    SUM([_C]) AS C,
    SUM([_Python]) AS Python,
    SUM([_JAVA]) AS JAVA,
    SUM([_CSS]) AS CSS,
    SUM([_JS]) AS JS,
    SUM([_CSharp]) AS CSharp,
    SUM([_SQL]) AS SQL
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Student Name],
            College,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,C,*",1,0) AS _C,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,Python,*",1,0) AS _Python,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,JAVA,*",1,0) AS _JAVA,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,CSS,*",1,0) AS _CSS,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,JS,*",1,0) AS _JS,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,C#,*",1,0) AS _CSharp,
            IIf(Skillz LIKE "*,SQL,*",1,0) AS _SQL
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    [Student Name],
                    College,
                    "," & Skills & "," AS Skillz
                FROM Students
            )
    )
GROUP BY College
```

...which returns:

```
College  C  Python  JAVA  CSS  JS  CSharp  SQL
-------  -  ------  ----  ---  --  ------  ---
ABC      4       4     4    1   1       0    0
UT       1       0     0    1   1       0    1
XYZ      3       3     0    0   0       0    0
```

**Note:** As you can see, working with the data in its current form will continue to make your life harder than it needs to be. Perhaps you will take this as yet another **strong** hint that you should ***fix your data model!***

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Also, If I need to group them as College and Gender, then simply adding GROUP BY COllege, Gender does not seem to work. ACCESS asks me for Gender parameter value? What's that all about?

Comment: Hey I've marked your answer right, but have edited the question a little to include the Male/Female Columns. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @SLearner You've updated the question text but I don't see any 'M' or 'F' values in your sample data. Nonetheless, you should try integrating a Male/Female count into the results using the techniques that have already been presented in the existing answer and then if you have a *specific* issue then you should create a new question for it. (It gets really tedious when people ask a question, get an answer, and then keep making substantive changes to the question. Sort of like "feature creep"....)

Answer (score 0):

Storing comma separate values in a single field is never a good idea. This is sometimes referred to as a SQL Antipattern. You're using a relational database so make it relational.

Create a separate table called Skills and put a foreign key field in it that matches your studentId field.

For the final result, to get the kind of view you want I think you will need to use a cross tab query.

Comment: Yup, I read up on it. Sadly theres nothing I can do now to alter the table structure. However, @GordThompson gave the right hack for my problem.